# Mongoose Updating Property Not in Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am attempting to set up a CRUD app which allows people to mark certain services as complete or incomplete.
Over time the services will likely change, some added, some removed, so I am trying to figure out if I can remove services from the schema but retain the ability for the older documents to have those services updated.

Here is the relevant part of my schema:

```
  services: {
    tom: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: "Top of Mind",
        required: true
      },
      status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true
      }
    },
    two: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: "Service Two",
        required: true
      },
      status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true
      }
    },
    three: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: "Service Three",
        required: true
      },
      status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
```

I set the strict property to false in hopes of updating any additional service even if it wasn't present in the schema.
For example, in the Mongo Atlas collection I manually added a service to one document like so:

```
test: {
  name: "Test Service", 
  status: false
}
```

This works fine when reading the data and is present when performing an update on the request up to the point where I try to change test.status.
The entire document is returned, including the test object under services, but `doc.services.test` is undefined which means I can't edit the status of "test".

edit:
Here is the services object which is returned when finding the document:

```
{ 
  tom: { name: 'Top of Mind', status: true },   
  two: { name: 'Service Two', status: true },   
  three: { name: 'Service Three', status: true },   
  test: { name: 'Service Test', status: false } 
}
```

doc.services.test returns undefined

Is there a workaround here, or does the "test" service need to be present in the schema in order to update it?

Comment: Here is the services object which is returned when finding the document:  ```{ tom: { name: 'Top of Mind', status: true },
  two: { name: 'Service Two', status: true },
  three: { name: 'Service Three', status: true },
  test: { name: 'Service Test', status: false } }```  doc.services.test returns undefined

Comment: It would be nice if you include in the question what you mentioned in the comment

Comment: updated.  For some reason didn't think to edit the question.

Comment: Can I take look it my own? nock me here. www.facebook.com/talha.aiubian